# Align three divs horizonatally. Need Advice

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm having trouble making my work neater. I'm really trying to learn how to simplify my efforts. But I start first with putting everything on the screen and then div'n the elements out. After I've seen all my elements, I tackle the css.

```css
.left {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width: 33%;
}
.middle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 3px 10px 3.5px;
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width: 33%;
}
.right {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: right;
  height: 400px;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <p id="logo">GRAPEFRUIT</p>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Download</li>
  <p id="fund">KickStarter</p>
</div>
<div id="top">
  <h1>Split Screen Messeging - Texting With Motion Images!</h1>
</div>
<div class="left" id="preview"></div>
<div class="middle" id="preview"></div>
<div class="right" id="preview"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish and what goes wrong with the code you've attempted?

Comment: What does "*div'n the elements out*" mean?

Comment: I think Timberzx is asking people to make the work neater and cleaner.

Comment: My terminology is not the best. Been at this for only a month. But I appreciate all who took their time to help out!

Answer (score 1):

**Link to see it work on jsFiddle --**
 http://jsfiddle.net/a1ynzr7p/1/

```
    <div id="header">
       <p id="logo"> GRAPEFRUIT</p>
       <li>Home</li>
       <li>Download</li>
       <p id="fund">KickStarter<p>
     </div>
     <div id="top">
     <h1>Split Screen Messeging - Texting With Motion Images!</h1>
     </div>
    <div class="evenThree" id="preview">LEFT
    </div>
    <div class="evenThree" id="preview">MIDDLE
    </div>
    <div class="evenThree" id="preview">RIGHT
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.evenThree{float:left; width:33%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use `display:flex;` on the parenting container of those three items.

http://jsfiddle.net/kqxyqL0f/3/

```css
.contentWrapper {
    display:flex;
}
.column {
    width:33%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <p id="logo">GRAPEFRUIT</p>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Download</li>
    <p id="fund">KickStarter
        <p>
</div>
<div id="top">
     <h1>Split Screen Messeging - Texting With Motion Images!</h1>

</div>
<div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="column" id="preview">TESTING LEFT</div>
    <div class="column" id="preview">TESTING MID</div>
    <div class="column" id="preview">TESTING RIGHT</div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Since `.contentWrapper` is a flex container, `vertical-align:top; display:inline-block;` does not apply. You can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create three columns (aligning div's horizontally)? You can simply wrap each column (left, middle and right) with a class that applies: `float:left` and `width:33%`.

As seen here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AaronVanston/b5a99ycw/)

```css
.col-3 {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">Left</div>
    <div class="col-3">Middle</div>
    <div class="col-3">Right</div>
</div>
```

Also some tips to help your code:

- ID's are non re-usable, don't repeat them throughout the code. Either change them to a class or change the ID to be unique.
- Make sure all the `<li>` elements are wrapped in a `<ul>` or `<ol>` tag

Comment: Thank you so much for the additional tip, I've always wondered how it differed from each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do these two things.  See the boxes 1 - 3, they're using DIV with CSS `display: table-cell`.  Easier to get the contents inside centered in the box.  The DIV containing Boxes 4, 5, and 6 are using `display: inline-block` - they're more flexible with using margins between them, but, you'll have to do something special to make the text go center (wrap it in `<span>`).

Or you can learn Twitter-Bootstrap (look it up).  You'll be far better off with it when applying layouting for websites especially when your requirements are to make it mobile friendly.

```css
.container {display: table;margin-bottom:30px}
.set {
  display:table-cell;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:#9a9a9a;
  border:1px solid #444;
}

.set2 {
  display:inline-block;
  width:140px;
  height:90px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#A75b5b;
  margin: auto 10px;
  border:1px solid #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="set">Box 1</div>
  <div class="set">Box 2</div>
  <div class="set">Box 3</div>  
  </div>


  <div class="set2">Box 4</div>
  <div class="set2">Box 5</div>
  <div class="set2">Box 6</div>
```